# Indoor Tree Identification (light woody bark, small green leaves)

Tags: identification

What is this indoor tree? It was on a recent RH catalog.

[image]

Comment: They are often fake

Answer (score 2):

The picture is not definitive due to the low resolution but chances are it is a [Ficus benjamina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_benjamina).  Both a popular interior tree and much abused by placing it in low light. It is native to East Asia and grows into a large tree but can tolerate lower light levels.

Identification keys:

- brown bark with shallow ridges
- fairly loose canopy typical of growth in low light

Comment: I actually thought it was a fake ficus, although it's very tall and not as full as the fake ones I've seen.

Comment: @Jurp  that is quite probable too. For these photo shoots the designer does not want to bother with live plants that can shed leaves or need water